# Download file success but status on debug is canceled?

Tags: flutter, dart

I create a function to download file with [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) package in my flutter application. But here I'm a little confused, why is my download status on the console log is **failed**/**canceled**, but the file was successfully downloaded on my device? Please I need advice.

Here is my controller

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:smps_flutter/helpers/global.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

class ReportController extends GetxController {
  RxString defaultDropdown = "ALL".obs;
  RxList<String> listDropdown = <String>[
    'ALL',
    'PROCEED - IN REVEW',
    'PROCEED - TO BRAND',
    'REJECTED - TIMELINE LESS THAN 45 DAYS',
    'REJECTED - UNSUITABLE BRAND',
  ].obs;

  RxBool rejected = false.obs;
  RxBool forwardToOtherFunction = false.obs;
  RxBool processFUForm = false.obs;
  RxBool reviewByCEBrand = false.obs;
  RxBool reviewByHOP = false.obs;
  RxBool canceled = false.obs;
  RxBool done = false.obs;

  RxBool readyForDownload = false.obs;
  RxString linkDownload = "".obs;

  RxBool permissionGranted = false.obs;

  final ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();
  String? downloadTaskId;
  RxInt downloadTaskStatus = 0.obs;
  RxInt downloadTaskProgress = 0.obs;
  RxBool isDownloading = false.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    initDownloadController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    disposeDownloadController();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> reqPermission() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin plugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    AndroidDeviceInfo android = await plugin.androidInfo;
    if (android.version.sdkInt < 33) {
      if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
        permissionGranted.value = true;
      } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
        await openAppSettings();
      } else if (await Permission.audio.request().isDenied) {
        permissionGranted.value = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (await Permission.photos.request().isGranted) {
        permissionGranted.value = true;
      } else if (await Permission.photos.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
        await openAppSettings();
      } else if (await Permission.photos.request().isDenied) {
        permissionGranted.value = false;
      }
    }
  }

  initDownloadController() {
    log('DownloadsController - initDownloadController called');
    _bindBackgroundIsolate();
  }

  _bindBackgroundIsolate() async {
    log('DownloadsController - _bindBackgroundIsolate called');
    final isSuccess = IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
      _port.sendPort,
      'downloader_send_port',
    );

    log('_bindBackgroundIsolate - isSuccess = $isSuccess');

    if (!isSuccess) {
      _unbindBackgroundIsolate();
      _bindBackgroundIsolate();
      return;
    } else {
      _port.listen((message) {
        downloadTaskId = message[0];
        downloadTaskStatus.value = message[1];
        downloadTaskProgress.value = message[2];

        if (message[1] == 2) {
          isDownloading.value = true;
        } else {
          isDownloading.value = false;
          Global.bottomSnackBarSuccess(
            "Reporting file just arrived on your phone",
          );
        }
      });
      await FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(registerCallback);
    }
  }

  disposeDownloadController() {
    _unbindBackgroundIsolate();
  }

  void _unbindBackgroundIsolate() {
    log('DownloadsController - _unbindBackgroundIsolate called');
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static registerCallback(String id, int status, int progress) {
    log("DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = $id, status = $status, progress = $progress");

    final SendPort? send =
        IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port');
    send!.send([id, status, progress]);
  }

  Future<void> downloadFile({required String url}) async {
    log('DownloadsController - downloadFile called');
    log('DownloadsController - downloadFile - url = $url');
    isDownloading.value = true;

    late String downloadDirPath;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      downloadDirPath = (await getDownloadsDirectory())!.path;
    } else {
      downloadDirPath = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    }
    downloadTaskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
      url: url,
      headers: {}, // optional: header send with url (auth token etc)
      savedDir: downloadDirPath,
      saveInPublicStorage: true,
      showNotification:
          true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
      openFileFromNotification:
          true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
    );
  }

  String getDownloadStatusString() {
    late String downloadStatus;

    switch (downloadTaskStatus.value) {
      case 0:
        downloadStatus = 'Waiting For Download';
        break;
      case 1:
        downloadStatus = 'Enqueued';
        break;
      case 2:
        downloadStatus = 'Downloading';
        break;
      case 3:
        downloadStatus = 'Failed';
        break;
      case 4:
        downloadStatus = 'Canceled';
        break;
      case 5:
        downloadStatus = 'Paused';
        break;
      default:
        downloadStatus = "Error";
    }

    return downloadStatus;
  }
}
```

And here is my view

```
Obx(
() => controller.isDownloading.value
  ? Column(
      children: [
        MyText.titleSmall(
          controller.getDownloadStatusString(),
          fontWeight: 600,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: MyText.titleSmall(
            "Download Progress",
            fontWeight: 600,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            value:
                controller.downloadTaskProgress.value.toInt() / 100,
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
  : Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, top: 36),
      child: MyButton(
        elevation: 0,
        padding: MySpacing.y(20),
        borderRadiusAll: 4,
        onPressed: () {
          controller.downloadFile(
              url: "https://storage.googleapis.com/approachcharts/test/5MB-test.ZIP");
        },
        child: Center(
          child: MyText.bodyMedium(
            "DOWNLOAD REPORT",
            color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
            letterSpacing: 0.8,
            fontWeight: 700,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
),
```

I don't know why my result status at

```
MyText.titleSmall(
  controller.getDownloadStatusString(),
  fontWeight: 600,
  fontSize: 18,
),
```

`getDownloadStatusString()` always get `Canceled`?. When I check on debug console it's the same status, failed, but file successfully downloaded on my device. Is there something missing with my code?

Here is the error log from my debug console

```
[log] DownloadsController - downloadFile called
[log] DownloadsController - downloadFile - url = https://storage.googleapis.com/approachcharts/test/5MB-test.ZIP
D/DownloadWorker(19953): DownloadWorker{url=https://storage.googleapis.com/approachcharts/test/5MB-test.ZIP,filename=null,savedDir=/data/user/0/com.projectsmps.smps_flutter/app_flutter,header={},isResume=false,status=ENQUEUED
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: https://storage.googleapis.com/approachcharts/test/5MB-test.ZIP, status: RUNNING, progress: 0}
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 0
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Open connection to https://storage.googleapis.com/approachcharts/test/5MB-test.ZIP
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Headers = {}
I/trustAllHosts(19953): checkServerTrusted
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Content-Type = application/zip
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Content-Length = 6207471
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Charset = null
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Content-Disposition = null
D/DownloadWorker(19953): fileName = 5MB-test.ZIP
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update too frequently!!!!, this should be dropped
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 1
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update too frequently!!!!, this should be dropped
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 12
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: 5MB-test.ZIP, status: RUNNING, progress: 23}
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 23
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: 5MB-test.ZIP, status: RUNNING, progress: 34}
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 34
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: 5MB-test.ZIP, status: RUNNING, progress: 45}
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 45
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update too frequently!!!!, this should be dropped
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 56
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: 5MB-test.ZIP, status: RUNNING, progress: 67}
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 67
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: 5MB-test.ZIP, status: RUNNING, progress: 78}
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 78
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: 5MB-test.ZIP, status: RUNNING, progress: 89}
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 89
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: 5MB-test.ZIP, status: RUNNING, progress: 100}
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 2, progress = 100
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update too frequently!!!!, but it is the final update, we should sleep a second to ensure the update call can be processed
[log] DownloadsController - registerCallback - task id = 13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, status = 4, progress = -1
D/DownloadWorker(19953): Update notification: {notificationId: 2, title: https://storage.googleapis.com/approachcharts/test/5MB-test.ZIP, status: FAILED, progress: -1}
W/System.err(19953): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.projectsmps.smps_flutter.flutter_downloader.provider
W/System.err(19953):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getFileProviderPathsMetaData(FileProvider.java:664)
W/System.err(19953):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:695)
W/System.err(19953):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:645)
W/System.err(19953):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:449)
W/System.err(19953):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.IntentUtils.buildIntent(IntentUtils.kt:19)
W/System.err(19953):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.IntentUtils.validatedFileIntent(IntentUtils.kt:36)
W/System.err(19953):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.downloadFile(DownloadWorker.kt:446)
W/System.err(19953):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.doWork(DownloadWorker.kt:206)
W/System.err(19953):    at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
W/System.err(19953):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
W/System.err(19953):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
W/System.err(19953):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19953): Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=13e24ed7-5397-4a74-8ba6-65935e6ed909, tags={ flutter_download_task, vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker } ]
```